# when i use "tns preview" to start an android emulator i get an error code

Tags: android, nativescript, emulation, device

i want to preview my nativescript code on an android emulator which as i use the command line which is, i navigated to my app folder which which was successfully but when i type "tns preview" to run an android emulator to see my code in action i get

```
Found peer TypeScript 3.1.6

#
# Fatal
process OOM in insufficient memory to create an Isolate
#

TypeScript compiler failed with exit code 3221225477
```

and an android emulator is connected successfully, even nativescript notice the emulator, please what do i do

i have tried the Nativescript sidekick to start the emulator but the nativescript sees the android emulator and it did not report an error indication but when i select the android emulator and click "Run on Device" i get

```
Build failed. TypeScript compiler failed with exit code 3221225477
```

even i have tried using my android device for previewing it which i install the nativescript playground & nativescript preview but if i scan the QR Code it is not previewing, please help out

please i need a solution

Answer (score 0):

Preview is to be used with real device for quick testing. The basic idea is to avoid setting up whole iOS / Android SDKs on your local machine.

> Produces a QR code which can be used to preview the app on a device without the need to install various SDKs and tools or configure your environment for local iOS or Android development.
>
> To scan the QR code and deploy your app on a device, you need to have
>   the NativeScript Playground app:
>
> App Store (iOS):
>   https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nativescript-playground/id1263543946?mt=8&ls=1
>
> Google Play (Android):
>   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nativescript.play

Comment: Manoj i have tried that but instead it will keep on scanning the QR Code without any preview

Comment: Just to make sure, you are testing on real device with preview app, it keeps scanning?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view your app on your android emulator, run the command 
'tns run android --emulator'
This is assuming you already have an emulator set up on your machine.
To see a list of your available devices run the command 
'tns device'
If you have not set up an emulator follow setup here: https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/android-virtual-devices